# Chrome ignoring CSS styling for input range

Tags: css, html

Making a simple web mixing thing, but Chrome doesn't seem to like my CSS for the thumbs on my range sliders. The tracks for them seem to be working well enough (or well enough that I can sort out anything I'm not happy with).

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  width: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #434546;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #434546;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" />
</div>
```

Most of this came from, but I made a couple of changes: http://danielstern.ca/range.css/#/

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 57.0.2987.110

Comment: Like a mixing desk fader, so with a rectangular thumb, taller than it is wide. I can set the exact values and play around with it after I get it to work properly, but the main issue is that Chrome is ignoring the values I'm putting in.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution in a codepen snippet, you have to set `-webkit-appeareance: none` to the field:

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
}
```

Whole example https://codepen.io/freoted/pen/bENyzL

Comment: should note that this solution does not work when trying to make the slider vertical with -webkit-appearance: 'slider-vertical'; as you cannot have 'none' and 'slider-vertical' at the same time: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341071

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me too, the solution was easy but it make me lost a lot of time investigating why. The solution is put `-webkit-appearance: none;` in thumb and in the runnable-track, in both. (chrome things I guess)

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 20px;
height: 80%;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
background: #434546;
border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
border: 1px solid #000000;
height: 40px;
width: 30px;
border-radius: 3px;
background: #ffffff;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

This article can help you http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

Answer (score -2):

```
working the same for me 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><style type="text/css">
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  width: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #434546;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #434546;
}</style></head><body >
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" />
</div></body></html>
```